# Nginx routing with hashtag and to different pages

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I need to update my nginx .conf file for a site that will be moved on another domain and to another platform.
My conf looks like this:

```
server 
{
  listen       443;
  server_name  site1.domain.com;
  return 301 https://site2.com$request_uri;
}
```

plus certificates etc.

The specific question is that i need to forward/rewrite 4 specific page, with the hashtag, to 4 different links.

> site1.domain.com/request/#/ -> site2.com

> site1.domain.com/request/#/ordering -> site2.com/ordering

> site1.domain.com/request/#/products -> site2.com/products

> site1.domain.com/request/#/distribution -> site2.com/distribution

What's the best method to achieve this?

Thanks,

Mvrck

i've tried different regex, but i'm not so skilled in that.

Comment: You cannot do this in Nginx. Anything from the `#` onwards is called the [URI fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment) and is not part of the request sent to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've made a lot of research and it seems that there is no way to achieve it.
Based on this, i will only set a redirect from site1 to site2, but there is another problem: 

When i go to "site1.domain.com/request/#/products" -> in the browser i'm redirect to "site2.com/#/products"... it seems like the browser forward the part after the ashtag. 

Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?